# .css() on DOM element not activating

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Been trying for hours, but can't get this to work.

If I go direct

```
$(.button).click(function(event){
    var graham = window.document.childNodes[1].childNodes[2].childNodes[1].childNodes[9];
    $(graham).css('color', 'red');
)};
```

But instead of just typing out the DOM node directly, if I cycle it through a loop like:

> ```
> $(.button).click(function(event) {
>   js = (js.slice(0, -1)).split(",");
>   for(x = 0; x< js.length; x++) {
>       js[x] = "childNodes[" + js[x] + "]";
>   }
>   js = "window.document." + js.join(".");
>     $(js).css('color', 'red');
> ```
>
> )};

Nothing happens onclick. Is there something wrong with using 'window.document' as a string and appending it to the childNodes data? I thought this would be straight forward, but can't get it to work!..

Comment: `$(.button)` should be `$('.button')`

Comment: what is the value of variable `js`

Comment: Seems like you should be able to easily answer your own question using the developer tools of your favorite browser. Set a breakpoint on the click event handler and step through the code.

Comment: The problem is that jQuery sees `js` as a string not an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that jQuery sees `js` as a string not an object :

This changes the Stackoverflow website `<body>` to green :

```
$(window.document.childNodes[1].childNodes[2]).css('background', 'green');
```

This doesn't :

```
$('window.document.childNodes[1].childNodes[2]').css('background', 'green');
```

However this does :

```
$(eval('window.document.childNodes[1].childNodes[2]')).css('background', 'green');
```

Try it in your console.

You need to do :

```
$(eval(js)).css('color', 'red');
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! I knew it was something simple and stupid related to using strings for the DOM structure. Thanks for taking the time to write out code examples, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using jQuery it is not necessary to search nodes with the native NodeList object via childNodes. Just rely on a jQuery selector.

If jQuery is not used, you can rely on native DOM methods such as querySelector, getElementById, getElementsByTagName, getElementsByClassName, etc.

Comment: I know. I'm building this piece to handle a universal set of use cases though. I can't assume the element has a class or ID, or any marker. And I also need to target the exact node, not ALL <p>'s, or ALL <a>'s for example